# How do I use specific Node version in current terminal window only with homebrew?

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew, open-source

I've installed Node@10 `brew` previously and prefer to continue using only `brew` without `nvm` etc.

All of my projects are on Node@10. Now I need to use Node@12 for just one.

How do I set node version to 12 only in the current terminal window with brew?

Comment: Would you be amenable to fixing the symbolic link so v10 is “default” on the shell and have a node-v12 sym link for the new projects? Making this about a single terminal app window might be a lot of work... https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/362197/5472 I don’t like `nvm` much either but `asdf` is quite handy